# Not consistent issue with Bootstrap menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Every once in a while my second level links don't work. I would say 8 out of 10 times they work. The console isn't showing any errors when the menu doesn't work, and it is very inconsistent.

Anyway, here's the Bootstrap code for the second level. Can anyone see if something in this is causing the issue?

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="dropdown">Restaurants</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="/asian.php">Asian</a></li>
    <li><a href="/american.php">American</a></li>
    <li><a href="/mexican.php">Mexican</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: Try to reproduce this issue on CodePen and let us know the result.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted looks fine. You're dealing with another problem. Here are a couple things you should check out.

1. If you're loading from a cdn or server, look in your chrome tools    network tab to confirm your css and js files are loading correctly. Could be a latency issue.
2. Add the default navbar and try to see if it has the same issue at the same time, if it works fine you have a problem with code outside of that snippet. Copy all the navbar code, create a codepen and try to fix the problem in an isolated environment.